# How to login with hash class in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1

I want use hash class for hash my passwords.
because I want slat password with My policy.
I have controller like this:

```
 public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
   $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:8'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    } else {
        $user=User::where('username',$request['username'])->where('group_id',1)->get()->toArray();
        $password=new PasswordController;
        $request['password'] = $password->create_password_str($request['username'],$request['password']);
       if(isset($user[0]['password'])&&Hash::check($request['password'], $user[0]['password'])){
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        } else {
            return view('auth.login')->with('flag',5);
        }
    }
}
```

I use username after login like this

```
{{Auth::user()->username}}
```

show me error

> Trying to get property of non-object

I add this code before redirect but dont work.

```
  Auth::login($request['username']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not use the laravel builtin function so it did not store the user in a `SESSION` and it throws an error while you try to fetch a user data which  actually does not exists. Here's how to authenticate with laravel auth attempt function

```
if( Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]))
{
   //redirect to dashboard
} else
{
  //invalid credentials
}
```

**Note :** Even you do not need to convert your password to hash. laravel is intelligent enough to convert it to hash.

**Update:** If you want to use custom salt for your project you could [checkout this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306196/override-laravel-4s-authentication-methods-to-use-custom-hasing-function).

Comment: I know this. but attempt class use bcrypt and You not add own salt in. I want add my slat in hash.

Comment: No is not safe. because you can not add your salt in this. for example If hacker access your database he can create bcrypt own password and replace the admin password

Comment: @paranoid check my updated answer I've added a link which should fix your problem.